# Connecting to current selenium browser window with session id

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to connect to existing browser window from selenium RC.
As per [Exposing the selenium browser session id](http://www.touspassagers.com/2010/11/exposing-the-selenium-browser-session-id/), it seems if I get the current session on selenium RC, I could accomplish this.

Has anyone tried it before?

I'm using Java.

Comment: I guess I need to modify the java client on my side.

Comment: Is this an existing Selenium browser window or just a regular browser window?

Comment: Existing selenium browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the selenium java client to return me the session id, I could reuse for subsequent actions on the browser.
Hope newer version of selenium provide this functionality.
Thanks
Nayn

Comment: i achieved the same for php using a simple assignment in test case setup function : $this->sessionId = session_id(); works like a charm.